# why is this code's vector iterator not stopped?

Tags: c++

I am a very beginner for c++.

When I do exercise problem, I met the problem.

under code !!

I expected do from factors.size() to 0.
But, It didn't work like.
It return to me, from factors.size() to 0, -1(4294967295), -2(4294967294), ...

Why is this code not return 0 and not stop?

If you know, please let me explain.

```
    vector<int>::size_type iter;
    for (iter=factors.size()-1 ; iter >= 0 ; --iter)
    {
        //cout << factors[iter];
        cout << iter;
        cout << " : " << factors[iter] << endl;
    }
```

```
//----------- Full Code --------------//
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int find_max_bit(int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    int nTmpNum = 0;
    int nMaxJisu = 0;
    int ret = 0;

    nTmpNum = n;
    while (nTmpNum >= 1)
    {
        nMaxJisu++;

        nTmpNum = (int) (nTmpNum / 2);
    }

    ret = (int) nMaxJisu;

    return ret;
}

std::vector<int> binary_factors(int n)
{
    std::vector<int> factors;

    cout << "find_max_bit : " << find_max_bit(n) << endl;

    factors.reserve(find_max_bit(n));

    int bi_Num;
    for (int i = 0; i < find_max_bit(n) ; i++)
    {
        bi_Num = n >> i & 0x1;
        cout << bi_Num;
        factors.push_back(bi_Num);
        cout << " : size : " << factors.size() << endl;
    }

    return factors;
}

int main()
{
    int nNum;

    cin >> nNum;

    while (nNum < 0 || nNum > 31)
    {
        cin >> nNum;
    }


    auto factors = binary_factors(nNum);
   
    cout << "factors.size() = " << factors.size() << endl;

    cout << nNum;
    
    for (auto it = factors.begin(); it != factors.end(); ++it)
        cout << ' ' << *it;
    cout << endl;

    vector<int>::size_type iter;
    for (iter=factors.size()-1 ; iter >= 0 ; --iter)
    {
        //cout << factors[iter];
        cout << iter;
        cout << " : " << factors[iter] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternative: [Use reverse iterator.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin)

Comment: `iter` is `size_t`, `iter >= 0` is always true.

Comment: better don't call a loop counter `iter`, its not an iterator but an index

Comment: Use an actual iterator. Or better `for(const auto& item : factors)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop:

```
for (iter=factors.size()-1 ; iter >= 0 ; --iter)
```

is guaranteed to never terminate, since `iter`, which is `vector<int>::size_type`, is an unsigned type. When you subtract 1 from an unsigned 0 you get a large positive number, instead of a negative number. Since `iter` never becomes negative, the loop condition is never satisfied.

You can fix this by making `iter` a signed integer:

```
for (auto iter = static_cast<int>(factors.size()) - 1 ; iter >= 0 ; --iter)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `vector<int>::size_type` is an unsigned integer and that you're iterating backwards as though it were a signed integer. You are correct in your first expectation that it will iterate from

> `factors.size()-1` to 0 [Assuming `factors.size()` > 0]

However when `iter` reaches 0 in the statement `for (iter=factors.size()-1 ; iter >= 0 ; --iter)` the condition `iter >= 0` will be true causing the statement `--iter` to occur. This results results in `iter` underflowing and being equal to the maximum representable value for that unsigned type, in your case 4294967295. Importantly, iter doesn't become negative and the loop continues and invokes undefined behavior as it accesses memory out of bounds via the statement `factors[iter]`.

Here are two ways you could solve this problem.

1. If you need the index then change the for loop condition to this

   `for (auto iter=factors.size(); iter--;)`
2. If you only need the value then you can use a reverse iterator

   `for (auto iter=factors.rbegin(); iter != factors.rend(); ++iter)`